# epsilon-delta proof

Tags: real-analysis

Would anyone please give me a epsilon-delta proof:
when $x$ approaches to infinity, $$x\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt x=\infty\;.$$

What I did was:

$$\left(x\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt x\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt x}
=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt x}$$

Then, what is the next step?

Comment: @FlyByNight: It’s not good to correct an error of understanding in a question, as you did in your edit: the OP needs to be informed of the problem.

Comment: It is incorrect to write $x\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt x=\infty$; what you mean is that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt x)=\infty\;,$$ which is a very different statement. There is no number that you can substitute for $x$ to make your version true.

Comment: Brian, instead of un-doing my correction, why didn't you leave a note for the OP to tell him/her why it had been changed? The net result here seems to have been that you've wasted my time. Well done Brian. Hope you're happy. All this because I didn't like one of your answers. Do you intend to bug me for the rest of your life?

Comment: @FlybyNight: Did you dislike one of my answers? I honestly don’t remember. I undid it because I don’t approve of making substantive changes to a question without the OP’s permission, and as a courtesy I left you a note explaining why I undid it. (By the way, it’s sheer accident that I even saw your comment; you need to precede my name with the '@' character for your comment to appear in my inbox.)

Comment: Brian, That's funny. When you click "edit" the following message is displayed: "*We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits unless absolutely necessary*."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a cruder approach. Let $x$ be positive. Then $\sqrt{x+2}\gt \sqrt{x}$.

It follows that
$$x\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x}\gt x\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}=(x-1)\sqrt{x}.$$

Furthermore, if $x\gt 1$, then $(x-1)\sqrt{x}\gt x-1$.

Now it should be easy, given any $K$, however large, to come up with an $L$ such that if $x\gt L$, then $x-1 \gt K$.

**Remark:** We have **not** been asked, given $K$, to come up with the *cheapest* $L$ such that for $x$ beyond $L$, we have $x\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x} \gt K$.

Answer (score 1):

In response to edit, when you tried to multiply the equation by the conjugate you made a mistake $\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{x}$ is conjugate to $\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x}$, not $x\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{x}$. Instead what you can do is factor our $x$ first
$$x\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{x} = x\left(\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}\right)$$
I would then attempt to prove that the latter expression in brackets approaches infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Also, are you sure this is the right question? The two terms are so different in value
($O(x^{3/2})$ and $\sqrt{x}$) that this is an unlikely question.

Perhaps the real question is to show that 
$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x\sqrt{x+2}-x \sqrt x)=\infty$.
Then the conjugate expression would be of use.